# Lambda Expression with Join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following entities

1. Project
2. Component
3. ProjectComponent

I want to write a method like

```
GetProjectsByComponentId(int componentId)
{ /* some code*/}
```

Please help me write a lambda expression.

Snippet from EF generated schema:

```
public partial class ProjectComponent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProjectID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ComponentID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.ProjectComponents = new HashSet<ProjectComponent>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectComponent> ProjectComponents { get; set; }
}

public partial class Component
{
    public Component()
    {
        this.ProjectComponents = new HashSet<ProjectComponent>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectComponent> ProjectComponents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want to express the query something like this...    return ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.... I need help how to complete that expression

Comment: That example is looking for Projects with a given ProjectId, this is different, another example could be Project and Employee. Get me all Projects a given Emploee is associated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComponentIDUnfortunately you have provided very little amount of info, but I will try to help.

Assuming you have edmx or code first model:

```
ctx.Project.Include(p=>p.ProjectComponents).Where(p => p.ProjectComponents.Any(pc=>pc.ComponentID == id)).ToList();
```

or SQL

```
SELCT p.* FROM Project as p
INNER JOIN ProjectComponent as pc ON pc.ProjectID = p.ID
WHERE pc.ProjectID = @ID
```

Comment: I have included the schema generated by EF in original post above

Comment: I have updated my linqu query. I think it should works as intended.